# Guava: transform an List<Optional<T>> to List<T> keeping just present values

Tags: java, guava

Is there an elegant way of using Guava to transform from a list of optionals to a list of present values?

For example, going from

```
ImmutableList.of(
    Optional.of("Tom"), Optional.<String>absent(), Optional.of("Dick"),
    Optional.of("Harry"), Optional.<String>absent()
)
```

to a list containing just

```
["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
```

One approach would be:

```
List<T> filterPresent(List<Optional<T>> inputs) {
    return FluentIterable.from(inputs)
            .filter(new Predicate<Optional<T>>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(Optional<T> optional) {
                    return optional.isPresent();
                }
            }).transform(new Function<Optional<T>, T>() {
                @Override
                public T apply(Optional<T> optional) {
                    return optional.get();
                }
            }).toList();
}
```

But this is verbose.

Java 8 is not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: Your solution seems pretty good, yes it's verbose but if Java 8 is not an option, then I doubt, that you can find a better one. However, you could accept an `Iterable<Optional<T>>` for `inputs` instead of a `List`, and you could cache the `Predicate`/`Filter`, so it's not instantiated every time the method is called.

Comment: Sadly functional programming in Java before Java 8 _is_ verbose. If you want it shorter use procedural code - a loop would be much neater.

Comment: Just put the `Predicate` and `Function` in a class that you would call `Optionals` and reuse those when needed. Then, your code will be simpler and will reflect what you would expect, less verbosely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's actualy built-in method for this in Guava: [`presentInstances` in `Optional`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#presentInstances-java.lang.Iterable-):

> Returns the value of each present instance from the supplied optionals, in order, skipping over occurrences of `absent()`. Iterators are unmodifiable and are evaluated lazily.

Example:

```
List<Optional<String>> optionalNames = ImmutableList.of(
    Optional.of("Tom"), Optional.<String>absent(), Optional.of("Dick"),
    Optional.of("Harry"), Optional.<String>absent());

Iterable<String> presentNames = Optional.presentInstances(optionalNames); // lazy

// copy to List if needed
List<String> presentNamesList = ImmutableList.copyOf(presentNames);
System.out.println(presentNamesList); // ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
```

Comment: Just the ticket! Thanks.

Comment: And if you don't need any `List` method (ex. because you just iterate), don't copy created `Iterables` contents into list.

Comment: use `Lists.newArrayList(presentNames)`

Comment: @jiahut Only if you need mutability *and* `List` interface.

Answer (score 5):

Why not do it in the old-fashioned Java way:

```
List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
for (Optional<T> optional : inputs) {
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        result.add(optional.get());
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: +1 for use procedural code in a procedural language.

Comment: I'm a heavy proponent of Guava, and I like this one the best.  Succinct, performant, and most importantly, communicates intent the best.

Comment: not so great beacuse of the 'Optional as type for parameter used'-warning.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the predicate instances behind method calls to make the code more readable:

```
List<T> filterPresent(List<Optional<T>> inputs) {
    return FluentIterable.from(inputs).filter(present()).transform(value()).toList();
}

static <T> Predicate<Optional<T>> present() {
    return new Predicate<Optional<T>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Optional<T> optional) {
            return optional.isPresent();
        }
    };
}

static <T> Function<Optional<T>, T> value() {
    return new Function<Optional<T>, T>() {
        @Override
        public T apply(Optional<T> optional) {
            return optional.get();
        }
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no easier way in the pre-Java-8-life.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a method in a loop which returns an `Optional` and you want to create a `List` of the returned values which are present, then you can use the `toSet` method on the `Optional` in conjunction with the `addAll` method on the `List`, like so:

```
List<String> strings = newArrayList();
for (Long id : ids) {
   strings.addAll(getString(id).toSet());
}
```

This is useful if you want to return a `List`, rather than an `Iterable`, which you get from `Optional.presentInstances`.